# SQL Server row_number() over partition by, but ignore repeating categorical values

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I am trying to track different paths through multiple categories.  A simplified view of my table looks like this:

```
Table: customer_category

CustomerID   |  Category  |  Date
11111        |  A         |  2016-01-01
11111        |  B         |  2016-02-01
11111        |  C         |  2016-03-01
22222        |  A         |  2016-01-01
22222        |  A         |  2016-02-01
22222        |  A         |  2016-03-01
22222        |  C         |  2016-04-01
33333        |  A         |  2016-01-01
33333        |  B         |  2016-02-01
33333        |  C         |  2016-03-01
33333        |  C         |  2016-04-01
```

I can find the absolute paths by using this query:

```
with cat_order as (
    select CustomerID
          ,Category
          ,row_number() over (partition by CustomerID order by Date) as rnk
    from customer_category
),pivot as (
    select CustomerID
      ,max(case when rnk = 1 then Category else null end) as category_1
      ,max(case when rnk = 2 then Category else null end) as category_2
      ,max(case when rnk = 3 then Category else null end) as category_3
      ,max(case when rnk = 4 then Category else null end) as category_4
    from cat_order
    group by CustomerID
)
select category_1, category_2, category_3, category_4, count(*) as count
from pivot
group by category_1, category_2, category_3, category_4
```

;

This gives me the following:

```
category_1  |  category_2  |  category_3  |  category_4  |  count
A           |  B           |  C           |              |  1
A           |  A           |  A           |  C           |  1
A           |  B           |  C           |  C           |  1
```

What I want, though, is to ignore repeated categories, so that I would see

```
category_1  |  category_2  |  category_3  |  category_4  |  count
A           |  B           |  C           |              |  2
A           |  C           |              |              |  1
```

In my head, I think I would need to

1. omit any record where Category = lag(category)
2. rank over partition...
3. pivot with case statements
4. aggregate the results

It feels way overcomplicated.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean ignore repeated category.. all 1,2,3,4? In your result you got a c from category2 but the base doesn't has it.

Comment: When I say 'repeated category', I'm looking at how consumer 22222 goes through a sequence A A A C.  I don't care that they were in category A in three different measurements, only that they were an A and then a C (without going through category B), whereas the other two followed a progression from A -> B -> C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simpler way to do it as far as I can tell (given your data and your desired output). To get your desired results, you basically need to do the four steps you outlined (or some variation of it). You can "simplify" it in a way that doesn't require CTEs though. For example:

```
SELECT category_1 = P.[1],
       category_2 = P.[2],
       category_3 = P.[3],
       category_4 = P.[4],
       [Count] = COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT CustomerID,
           Category,
           rnk = SUM(checkprev) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *, checkprev = CASE WHEN LAG(Category) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY [Date]) = Category THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        FROM customer_category
    ) T
) AS T
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Category) FOR rnk IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS P
GROUP BY P.[1], P.[2], P.[3], P.[4];
```